# How to change app language runtime in swift (from inside app) withOut changing device language , iOS

Tags: ios, swift, localization

**Do I need to make @IBOutlets of all labels in there controllers (as shown in example) to assign there key corresponding language string or there is some better possible solution can be adopted, any response will be helpful 
Thanks**

```
@IBOutlet weak var languageChangeLabel: UiLabel!

languageChangeLabel.text = .localized("keyForLabel", language: languageCode)
// key is form .Strings files, language codes like "zh" for Chinese and "ar" for arabic (language localization
code) 

// and extension is 


 extension String {
    public static func localized(_ key: String, language: String? = nil) -> String {
        let language = language ?? Locale.preferredLanguages.first?.components(separatedBy: "-").first ?? "en"
        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: language, ofType: "lproj"), let bundle = Bundle(path: path) else {
            return Bundle.main.localizedString(forKey: key, value: nil, table: "Localizeable")
        }
        return bundle.localizedString(forKey: key, value: nil, table: "Localizeable")
    }
}
```